# OxyPlot Chart Not Displaying On Xamarin Forms Portable Application

Tags: c#, xamarin, charts, xamarin.forms, oxyplot

I'm creating a PieChart using OxyPlot here in my Xamarin.Forms (Portable) Application. I created a ViewModel named **PieViewModel** where in I declare the content of the Pie Chart. In my **SalesPage.XAML.cs**, I call the ViewModel and access the **salesmodel** in it. In my XAML code, I bind the **salesmodel** in my code.

However, I wasn't able to display the PieChart. Here are the codes I used:

**PieViewModel.cs**

```
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.Series;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

    namespace XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels
    {
        public class PieViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
        {
            private PlotModel modelP1;
            public PieViewModel()
            {
                modelP1 = new PlotModel { Title = "Pie Sample1" };

                dynamic seriesP1 = new PieSeries { StrokeThickness = 2.0, InsideLabelPosition = 0.8, AngleSpan = 360, StartAngle = 0 };

                seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Africa", 1030) { IsExploded = false, Fill = OxyColors.PaleVioletRed });
                seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Americas", 929) { IsExploded = true });
                seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Asia", 4157) { IsExploded = true });
                seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Europe", 739) { IsExploded = true });
                seriesP1.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Oceania", 35) { IsExploded = true });

                modelP1.Series.Add(seriesP1);

            }

            public PlotModel Model1
            {
                get { return modelP1; }
                set { modelP1 = value; }
            }


            public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

            protected void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
            {
                PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }

        }
    }
```

.

**SalesPage.XAML.cs**

```
using OxyPlot;
using OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels;



using Xamarin.Forms;

    namespace XamarinFormsDemo.Views
    {
        public partial class SalesPage : ContentPage
        {

            public SalesPage()
            {

            }


        }
    }
```

.
**SalesPage.XAML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms;assembly=OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms"
         xmlns:ViewModels="clr-namespace:XamarinFormsDemo.ViewModels;assembly=XamarinFormsDemo"
         x:Class="XamarinFormsDemo.Views.SalesPage"
         BackgroundImage="bg3.jpg"
         Title="Sales Page">



    <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding Model1}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

</ContentPage>
```

.
**MainActivity.cs**

```
using System;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using ImageCircle.Forms.Plugin.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android;

namespace XamarinFormsDemo.Droid
{
    [Activity(Label = "XamarinFormsDemo", Icon = "@drawable/recordsicon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
    public class MainActivity : AndroidActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
        {
            base.OnCreate(bundle);

            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
            OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlotViewRenderer.Init();
            LoadApplication(new App());
            ImageCircleRenderer.Init();
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me with this. I'm really getting confused on how the things are going. Thanks a lot.

Comment: For one thing, your `pvm` and your `salesmodel` are declared as local variables when they should be public properties for the binding to work.

Comment: @jstreet should I make something like this? >  public string salesmodel { get; set; } ? What datatype should I use?

Comment: Based on your code, `salesmodel` should be a `PlotModel`.

Comment: @jstreet I put this in my PieViewModel:  public PlotModel salesmodel {get;set;}
And this in my SalesPage.xaml.cs:  pvm.salesModel = pvm.Model1; Am I correct doing this?

Comment: Well.... you changed things a little bit: `salesmodel` was not a `PieViewModel` property.... and now, according to your change it is.... If that is the case, you don't need both `salesmodel` and `Model1`, only one of them would be enough. Please don't post code in the comments section. Instead, edit the code in your original question.

Comment: @jstreet Sorry for posting codes here Sir. Well if that's the case, in my PieViewModel I have declared the Model1. How can I access it in my XAML?

Comment: In your XAML, bind `PlotView` to `Model1`.

Comment: @jstreet I edited my codes Sir. I bind the PlotView to Model1 but nothing happened. Can you check if my xaml controls are correct?

Comment: Somewhere in your code, either in XAML or code behind, you need to create your `PieViewModel` and assign it to your `DataContext`.

Comment: I suggest you to follow a tutorial on how to do it because you're missing basic steps in a MVVM approach.

Comment: @jstreet In my XAML, I bind it like this Sir     <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding Model1}" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

Comment: Yes, that is ok.... but where is `PieViewModel` created?

Comment: @jstreet 
I've put my PieViewModel above, is that what I need to do? And what about the DataContext Sir? Sir thank you so much for helping me. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Yes, that is your implementation of `PieViewModel`, but you need to do something like `PieViewModel vm = new PieViewModel();` and then `DataContext = vm;`. These are basic steps in the MVVM approach. If you're not clear about that, please follow a tutorial.

Comment: @jstreet Sir can you please tell me more about that. I'm getting confused especially in creating Charts. How can I create that DataContext?

Comment: Probably your `SalesPage` already has a `DataContext` property. In that case, you could just add the 2 lines of code i mentioned before inside the constructor for `SalesPage`.

Comment: @jstreet Sir I think I don't have a DataContexxt for SalesPage. That's all the code I have. Please help me Sir.

Comment: I'll try to post some sample code later if i can. My `Xamarin.Forms` setup is not up and running right now.

Comment: @jstreet Alright Sir. Thank you so much.

Comment: @jstreet Sir what do I need to do next?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's some sample code:

**App: (Portable)**

```
    public class App : Application
    {
        public App()
        {
            MainPage = new Page3();
        }
    }
```

**XAML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:oxy="clr-namespace:OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms;assembly=OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms"
             x:Class="App26.Page3">
  <ContentPage.Content>
    <oxy:PlotView Model="{Binding MyModel}"></oxy:PlotView>
  </ContentPage.Content>
</ContentPage>
```

**CS:**

```
public partial class Page3 : ContentPage
{
    public MyViewModel vm { get; set; }

    public Page3()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        vm = new MyViewModel();

        BindingContext = vm;
    }
}
```

**ViewModel:**

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    public PlotModel MyModel { get; set; }

    public MyViewModel()
    {
        PieSeries pieSeries = new PieSeries();
        pieSeries.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Africa", 1030) { IsExploded = false, Fill = OxyColors.PaleVioletRed });
        pieSeries.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Americas", 929) { IsExploded = true });
        pieSeries.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Asia", 4157) { IsExploded = true });
        pieSeries.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Europe", 739) { IsExploded = true });
        pieSeries.Slices.Add(new PieSlice("Oceania", 350) { IsExploded = true });

        MyModel = new PlotModel();
        MyModel.Series.Add(pieSeries);
    }
}
```

**MainActivity: (Droid)**

```
 [Activity(Label = "App26", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, bundle);
        OxyPlot.Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.PlotViewRenderer.Init();
        LoadApplication(new App());
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Good Day Sir. I was able to figure it out yesterday. I just simply add this :   <ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ViewModels:PieViewModel/>
  </ContentPage.BindingContext>
to my code and the Chart appear. Thank you so much Sir for enlightening me. More powers :)

Comment: Yes Sir. Thank you for your effort in helping me. 'Til next time :)